# Callback is not defined while calling index

Tags: node.js, chai, sinon, sinon-chai

I have index.js

```
redshiftDetails: object
sqs: object
lambda: object
redshiftQueryParams: object

module.exports = function ({ redshiftDetails, sqs, lambda, redshiftQueryParams }, callback) {
    let metrics = [];

    async.waterfall([
        async.apply(helpers.bulkReceiveFromSQS, sqs),

        /**
         * Get temporary credentials for the redshift cluster
         * @param {Array} sqsMessagesList SQS messages
         * @param {Function} callback callback function
         */
        function getRedshiftCredentials (sqsMessagesList, callback) {
            logger.info('Obtaining redshift credentials...');
...
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H98S.png)

While writing test am doing:

```
redshiftDetails: {clusterId: 'someid', iamRole: 'somerole'}

it('should fail if the fetching temporary credentials of redshift fails', function (done) {
        stubbedGetTemporaryRedshiftCredentials.yields(new Error('call to getTemporaryRedshiftCredentials failed'));
        stubbedBulkReceiveFromSQS.yields(null);

        ingestionController({ redshiftDetails }, function (err) {
            expect(err).to.be.an('error');
            expect(err.message).to.be.equal('call to getTemporaryRedshiftCredentials failed');
            expect(stubbedRedshiftClose.callCount).to.be.equal(0);

            done();
        });
    });
```

But am getting a TypeError: `callback is not defined`
Am using function destructuring technique in my argument, maybe I am missing something there but unable to find out after much trying. Anyone sees a catch here !!

Stacktrace:

```
TypeError: callback is not a function
      at lambdas/binlogs-s3-to-redshift-ingestion-controller/lib/index.js:28:447
      at callCallback (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/behavior.js:101:25)
      at Object.invoke (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/behavior.js:145:27)
      at Object.functionStub (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/stub.js:127:47)
      at Function.invoke (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/spy.js:268:51)
      at Object.getTemporaryRedshiftCredentials (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/spy.js:90:30)
      at getRedshiftCredentials (lambdas/binlogs-s3-to-redshift-ingestion-controller/lib/index.js:28:193)
      at nextTask (node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5310:14)
      at next (node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5317:9)
      at node_modules/async/dist/async.js:958:16
      at callCallback (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/behavior.js:101:25)
      at Object.invoke (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/behavior.js:145:27)
      at functionStub (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/stub.js:127:47)
      at Function.invoke (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/spy.js:268:51)
      at bulkReceiveFromSQS (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/spy.js:90:30)
      at node_modules/async/dist/async.js:66:19
```

Comment: If the error you wrote is actually copied and not (mis-)typed manually, then the issue is that your variable is called `callback` (lower-case `c`) but you call `Callback()` (upper-case `C`) somewhere.

Comment: The code snippet you showed doesn't seem to include the line at which you got the error, by the way! (The call to the callback)

Comment: Hey @CherryDT thanks for the comments, i have edited my query. But while having function argument destructuring, can i pass objects like that ?

Comment: Yes. That's not related to your original question though. `callback is not defined` can _only_ show if you are calling it somewhere in a scope where it doesn't exist at all - if it'd be undefined, you'd get `callback is not a function` instead. Again, please show the line (and surrounding area) where the error occured. It's not in your code snippet.

Comment: (I get the feeling that this error is thrown at a totally different place entirely, because everywhere inside of the function you are exporting from `index.js` there should be a `callback` variable in scope!)

Comment: To find the place where the error occured, check the stack trace of the error. You should see the filename and the line number and column number next to it, e.g. `at something.something (/home/user/test/test.js:14:8)`

Comment: I have added the stacktrace though.

Comment: OK but where can I see this line 28 of  `lambdas/binlogs-s3-to-redshift-ingestion-controller/lib/index.js` then? (and why does it have 447 characters - is this a minified file?)

As I said before, please _show the line of code_ (and the surrounding area) where the error occured. It doesn't help me to see which line number if you don't show the contents of that line here.

Comment: I was able to find where the problem is, `async.apply(helpers.bulkReceiveFromSQS, sqs)` doesn't sends the required output to next function (`function getRedshiftCredentials (sqsMessagesList, callback) {`)  as argument due to which the issue is caused.